# How to insert backslash followed by single quote using paste0 in R?

Tags: r, escaping

I'm trying to separate the elements in a vector with \' and a comma using paste0. For example:

```
test_vector = c("test1", "test2", "test3")
```

I would like to use paste0 to generate the following output:

> \'test1\', \'test2\', \'test3\'

because the backslash character is an escape character itself,

```
paste0(test_vector, collapse = "\', \'")
```

generates the following:

> "test1', 'test2', 'test3"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
(x <- paste0("\\'", test_vector, "\\'", collapse = ", "))
# [1] "\\'test1\\', \\'test2\\', \\'test3\\'"
```

We can check the *actual* result with `cat()` (since the second backslash is only present when printed to the console).

```
cat(x)
# \'test1\', \'test2\', \'test3\'
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I didn't realize that the actual result needed to be visualized using the cat() function, which complicated matters from the beginning.